# Wordpress directly route to single Custom type result after searching

Tags: wordpress, search, routes, custom-type

After searching (so ?s=foobar), I change the query :

```
function SearchFilter($query) 
{
    // If 's' request variable is set but empty
    if(isset($_GET['s'])
    && empty($_GET['s'])
    && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $query->is_search = true;
        $query->is_home = false;
    }


     if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('post','myFooBarCustomType'));
    }

    return $query;
}
```

But after the query, wordpress routes to the search.php page and I want to route to the single-customType.php page with the only-one result of my query. (a direct to the answer route with the good URL like www.mywebsite/myCustomType/foobar)

I only want the search.php page for a null result or more than 1.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code, try adding this piece of code to your functions.php:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'search_redirect_to_first_result');
function search_redirect_to_first_result() {
    if (is_search()) {
        if (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            wp_redirect(get_permalink());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```